# Significance of request.getSession() and request.getSession(boolean createNew)

Tags: java, http, servlets

While using the `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` methods in Servlets, I realized that the official documentation of the Servlet API indicates that `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` returns a new session object if the current session has expired or has been invalidated.

Also, `HttpServletRequest.getSession(boolean createNew)` returns a new session when `createNew` is true and if the previous session no longer exists.

Normally, IMO, while designing the API, one would have designed these methods as `HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)` creating a new session if the previous session is invalid and the `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` returning the existing session if present, else returning null.

Is there any specific reason pertaining to this significant difference in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications are more likely to want the current session or to create a new one rather than the current session only if it exists. The API chosen by the Servlet EG is therefore written the way it is.